# What MySQL collation/character set should I use for English and Spanish?

Tags: php, mysql, character, collation

I'm building an PHP5 application with MySQL for English and Spanish speaking. Should I set the character set and collation to UTF8 and then convert everything into the database with mbstring? Or, should I use some kind of latin character set that supports both English and Spanish? The application is strictly US only and it doesn't need to support the full international range of languages.

I'm using CodeIgniter on most projects. I just noticed the CI Database settings.

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
```

So, I assume these two settings should be good. I assume I need to reset the MySQL database char set and any collation settings on the db and tables?

Comment: stick with utf8. regardless of how few (or many) languages you're supporting now, using utf8 now will eliminate the need for charset conversions down the road when the PHBs inevitably add more languages.

Answer (score 4):

Set the charset to UTF8 both in php **and** in the database.

Use collation `utf8_latin_ci` in all tables in the database.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-general.html

Comment: From my understanding, collation effects the comparison. From a comparison standpoint, will uft8_latin_ci make LIKE searches match more or less? Will A match À, Â and others?

Comment: Collation affects the sort order **and** the comparison. Not 100% sure what matches what. I suggest some experimentation. I don't think `A` matches `À`, `Â`, because they don't **sound** the same.

Comment: @jjwdesign, `utf8_latin_ci` is not new, it has been in there for many many years.

Comment: I seem to have the same problem. For a brand new install of XAMPP 'utf8_latin_ci' is not an option.
There are a few UTF8 general options, and a unicode. And a bunch of specific foreign languages, but no latin. Well there is a whole latin section, but that is not utf8 (as far as it is labeled anyways)

Answer (score 2):

I speak portuguese, so I use `utf8_general_ci` for database, `charset=UTF-8` in my html headers and I run a series of commands in my Connection class when it opens the link to force utf8 collation in the communication. This won't affect performance in a noticeble way so you can simply use it regardless of what language you are using.