# UTF8 database isn't storing spanish characters

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, utf-8

I have a WordPress database where all tables are set to `utf8_general_ci`. Some of my script reads in a remote CSV file and stores content to the database. If there are any spanish characters it won't store anything, just null. I tried `mb_convert_encoding($line[2],'UTF-8');` which now stores the data but converts the characters to question marks.

WordPress database settings in `wp-config` are:

```
/** Database Charset to use in creating database tables. */
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');

/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

Comment: Are you sure your Spanish characters are UTF-8 and not something else? It's often the case that they come in as Windows-1252.

Comment: Please look at: [What MySQL collation/character set should I use for English and Spanish?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894582/what-mysql-collation-character-set-should-i-use-for-english-and-spanish). That should help you.

Comment: @tadman - reached out to the person making the CSV to be sure they are encoding it correctly

Comment: @TomaszTurkowski - I've seen this too. Would require me to rebuild the database on a live site. I'd be up for it if I know that would work 100%.

Comment: @dcp3450 You can usually check the encoding in a text editor, or look to see if you've got single byte values in the string. If you're getting characters like `é` showing up as two bytes, that's more likely to be UTF-8. It's `C3 A9` in UTF-8, but `E9` in Windows-1252.

Comment: @dcp3450 maybe try it locally for one of the tables and check result.

Comment: `SELECT col, hex(col) FROM tbl` to see which encoding got stored.